# Why are kuid_t and similar data types of type struct?

Tags: c, linux-kernel

In the Linux kernel source, `kuid_t` is defined as a `typedef struct` that contains a single `uid_t` variable `val`. What's the reason to define `kuid_t` as a structure instead of a single `typedef uid_t kuid_t`? I see it as a bit overhead to declare a structure just for a single variable, and to access it you need to use `kuid_t.val`:

```c
typedef struct {
    uid_t val;
} kuid_t;
```

Instead of the following, which is pretty much the usual thing you would do:

```c
typedef uid_t kuid_t;
```

Comment: Perhaps to allow for the future where `kuid_t` contains other than a simply integer.

Comment: It ensures you don't pass a (hypothetical?) `kgid_t` where a `kuid_t` is wanted and vice versa.  It improves the type safety by avoiding implicit conversions of integer types.  Don't forget: a `typedef` is an alias for an existing type name, not a new type.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler : you should provide your comment as an answer to this interesting question question.

Comment: I think the answer is provided by the comment in "include/linux/uidgid.h": *The types defined in this header allow distinguishing which uids and gids in  the kernel are values used by userspace and which uid and gid values are the internal kernel values.  With the addition of user namespaces the values can be different.  Using the type system makes it possible for the compiler to detect when we overlook these differences.*

Answer (score 3):

<sup>*Converting my [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73593434/why-kuid-t-and-similar-data-types-are-of-type-struct?noredirect=1#comment129958315_73593434) into an answer.*</sup>

I'm not a party to the official reasoning of the kernel developers, but…

Using a structure (`typedef struct { uid_t val; } kuid_t;`) to encapsulate the UID ensures you don't pass a (hypothetical?) `kgid_t` (for GID) where a `kuid_t` is wanted and vice versa. It improves the type safety of the kernel code by avoiding implicit conversions between integer types.

If the code used simple numerical types like `typedef uid_t kuid_t;` and `typedef gid_t kgid_t;`, there's a good chance that the underlying type for `uid_t` and `gid_t` is the same, so you could easily pass a value of `uid_t` where the required type is `gid_t` or vice versa, and the compiler cannot detect the logic problem.

Don't forget: a typedef is an alias for an existing type name, not a new type.  Also, simple structures like the `kuid_t` shown in the question can be passed to functions by value just as efficiently as primitive types — but with the extra type checking.

Comment: _Using a structure to encapsulate the UID ensures you don't pass a (hypothetical?) kgid_t (for GID) where a kuid_t is wanted_, **I don't get that, can you provide an example of an error that might occur when using `typedef uid_t kuid_t` instead of a `typedef struct`?**

Comment: @sqinFaq what Jonathan mean is that both `kuid_t` and `kgid_t` are intrinsically just a `uid_t`, so doing `typedef int uid_t; typedef int gid_t; typedef uid_t kuid_t; typedef gid_t kgid_t;` technically works, but you can't detect any error if a function wants a `kgid_t` and gets passed a `kuid_t` instead, since they are effectively the same type. Encapsulating the types in a struct solves this problem. This is done everywhere in the kernel, another example is the various types for page tables: `pte_t`, `pmd_t`, `pud_t`, `pgd_t`, etc. which are all different `struct { unsigned long val; }`.